# How to sum up pair elements individually in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following method to sum up the pair elements in an array of pairs. I am new to scala and feel like there will be a better way than the following piece of code.

```scala
  def accumulate(results: Array[(Int, Int)]): (Int, Int) = {
    var x: Int = 0
    var y: Int = 0
    for (elem <- results) {
      x = x + elem._1
      y = y + elem._2
    }
    (x, y)
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`foldLeft`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#foldLeft%5C[B%5C](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B)).
*(BTW, I would also use [**List**](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html), instead of **Array**)*

```
results.foldLeft((0, 0)) {
  case ((accX, accY), (x, y)) =>
    (accX + x, accY + y)
}
```

Comment: Why would you use `List`?

Comment: @Andronicus as a general collection in Scala it is more common than **Array**. It is immutable, it has a predictable performance, it allows recursion, and supports an efficient prepend.

Answer (score 1):

All of the operations in [`scala.collection.ArrayOps`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/ArrayOps.html) are available on `Array[T]`.  In particular, you can `unzip` an array of pairs into a pair of arrays

```scala
val (xs, ys) = results.unzip
```

Summing a container is a standard use of `fold`

```scala
val x = xs.fold(0)(_ + _)
val y = ys.fold(0)(_ + _)
```

And then you can return the pair of values

```scala
(x, y)
```

https://scalafiddle.io/sf/meEKv6T/0 has a complete working example.